# Build a .deb package, choose install location

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, installation

How do I go about telling the Debian package where I want things installed to? From what I've managed to gather, it all comes down to the folder structure. Basically, I have "n" folders, all in a parent directory. Each folder needs to be able to create a separate .deb file, with its own contents. If I build from the parent, I can control that things are under "/FolderName", but the .deb then includes "n" folders, whereas I only want it to contain the individual instance.

For example, it has a folder structure of Parent/1, Parent/2, Parent/3, ... Parent/n. If I wanna make a package for Parent/1 I can't simply do `dpkg-deb --build . Output.deb` since I don't want Parent/2, Parent/3... Parent/n. I'd like to be able to go in and say though, "Okay, on install, put these files under opt", for example. Is there a flag, or command or anything like that that I can do so they don't instantly install under "/", or do I need to somehow alter my file structure and that's final?